# Differentiate Lite and Premium App on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, target

I'm making an app that has two targets :

- Premium
- Lite

Basically in my architecture, only the json config file that determines which assets are displayed on a version is different.

So let's say the premium app should load "config.json" and the lite version should load "config-lite.json".

I only need this string but I'm completely lost among the techniques used to differentiate targets (often dev and prod).

- My projet uses cocoa pods, should I (can I) use this to provide an environment variable ?
- Do you do this using a plist file ? Or a preprocessor macro ?
- Considering the update of this post, what is the workaround for preprocessor macros in swift ?

[This (great) article seems](https://www.raywenderlich.com/68613/create-paid-lite-version-iphone-app) to sum up very well what I need to do but the syntax of the preprocessor macros seem to no longer work, am I right ?

I'm sorry that I don't have code to provide, I'm just trying to establish a best practice that hopefully would help other developers !

Comment: seems to work pretty good for me

Comment: @Mingebag : Could you post a screenshot and/or protocol to set a... let's say "LITE" variable that I can use somewhere in my code please ?